# Thick 3D textured lines with constant screen width

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, line, vertex-shader

I'm trying to draw 3D textured lines with **constant screen width**. (OpenGL ES 2.0)

In reality what I wanted to have is simple "volumetric" lines with a minimum guaranteed (clamped) screen width. So that when they are very far away the don't become too thin.

Any input on how to get there would be very appreciated **BUT** I would also like to have some feedback on the problem that I'm facing right now. Most probably a misunderstanding of how perspective correct interpolation works...

So I have a triangle strip like this:

```
struct tVtx
{
  vec3  mPos;
  vec3  mDir;
  vec2  mTexCoord;
};

auto vtxs = std::vector< tVtx >{
  { vec3{ -1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{ -1,  1 } },
  { vec3{ -1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{ -1, -1 } },
  { vec3{ -1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  0,  1 } },
  { vec3{ -1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  0, -1 } },
  { vec3{  1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  0,  1 } },
  { vec3{  1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  0, -1 } },
  { vec3{  1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  1,  1 } },
  { vec3{  1,0,0 }, vec3{ 1,0,0 }, vec2{  1, -1 } }
};
```

and I transform it in "world" space like this:

```
pt1 = vec3{  -0.450794667,  0.454502404,-0.437951744 };
pt2 = vec3{   -0.248224616,0.682369053, -0.886776387 };

auto center = ( pt1 + pt2 ) * 0.5f;
auto right = normalize( pt2 - pt1 );
auto up = normalize( cross( vec3( 0,0,1 ), right ) );
auto forw = cross( right, up );
auto mtx = mat4{ vec4( right, 0.0 ), vec4( up, 0.0 ), vec4( forw, 0.0   ), vec4( center, 1.0f ) };
```

My vertex shader is something like:

```
attribute vec3  aPos;
attribute vec3  aDir;
attribute vec2  aTexCoord;

uniform mat4  uMVPMtx;
uniform vec2  uScreenExtent;  // half size of screen
uniform vec2  uInflate;       // amount of line "grow" in pixels

varying mediump vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
  vec4  clipPos1 = uMVPMtx * vec4( aPos, 1.0 );
  // get a point on "direction" line, transform in screen and then get screen space direction vector
  // don't know how to transform a direction vector from WORLD to SCREEN space, naive way does not work ( MVP * vec4( aDir, 0.0 ) )
  vec4  clipPos2 = uMVPMtx * vec4( aPos + aDir * 1000.0, 1.0 );
  vec2  ndc1 = vec2( clipPos1 ) / clipPos1.w;
  vec2  ndc2 = vec2( clipPos2 ) / clipPos2.w;
  vec2  sc1 = ndc1 * uScreenExtent;
  vec2  sc2 = ndc2 * uScreenExtent;
  vec2  dir = normalize( sc2 - sc1 ) * sign( clipPos1.w * clipPos2.w ); // reduce damage if points lie on opposite sides of origin
  vec2  perp = vec2( -dir.y, dir.x );
  vec2  sc = sc1 + dir * aTexCoord.x * uInflate.x + perp * aTexCoord.y * uInflate.y;

  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

  // bring back to clip space
  gl_Position = vec4( sc / uScreenExtent * clipPos1.w, clipPos1.zw );
}
```

Fragment shader is something like:

```
varying mediump vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
  mediump float dist = clamp( length( vTexCoord ), 0.0, 1.0 );

  gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( vec3( 1.0, 0.25, 0.25 ), vec3( 0.25, 1.0, 0.25 ), dist ), 1.0 );
}
```

NOTICE that aTexCoord go from -1 to 1!

What I get is something like:

[image: Screwed textured quad]

The above picture has uInflate.x = 0, so it does not have round caps...

What I would like to get is a quad with a centered red line, fading to green.
Is this because the way I alter the x and y coordinates in screen space without touching the z and w components gives triangles that are not co-planar anymore? I have a hard time visualizing this...

**UPDATE**
The triangles are co-planar in eye space but their size is quite different (in eye space). What looks like a quad on screen is not a quad anymore in eye space. I guess this is the main problem (because of perspective correct interpolation ??). The question remains: how to draw 3D textured lines with constant (or controlled) screen width. With 3D I mean lines that are depth tested with other 3D content.

Comment: I think you are way over thinking and doing complicated things. Just output x,y,0,1 for position and you should be all set. Look at any example shader that just blits a texture. Your vertex shader should be three lines or so...

Comment: The lines should be 3D, depth tested with other 3D content. Like "volumetric" lines (see [link](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/cg_VolumeLine/docs/VolumeLine.pdf)) but I need to fully control their screen space width. Thanks for the comment anyway.